# Symfony 1.2 not showing files at public folder

Tags: php, image, symfony1

I'm setting up a project made by 2 other colleagues and I'm have a problem when putting it online.

On my local machine, everything works like a charm but online I can´t link any file at public folder, php scripts, images etc...

Does anyone knows if there's anything at symfony config's that can make this behavior?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Take a look at error logs, they always give a clue.

Comment: Sure you mean 1.2 or either 2.1?

Comment: Sure it's 1.2-13 :) It's a project based in an old one, the other one is currently running with no problems, like this at my machine. I am hosting it at a cpanel account, don't know if it matters

Comment: one strangest thing I could do is that if I try to navigate to an well-formed url to a script .php, this will also redirect with the default route of the application

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out.

The images were visible if I link to them directly like www.example.com/uploads/1.png

But the rewrite rule was not working because the .php script was giving an error so the rule was ignored.

Re-arranged permissions of files and folders on public and now everything is working